# Returning a CSS element (for use in boundary checking)

Tags: css, html, adobe-edge

Is there a way to return a CSS element?

I was using Adobe Edge and adding some of my own code in their code tab, but in order to create boundaries I would need to keep track of margin-top or margin-left.  The following code works to move the element "woo" but I'm not sure how to call the elements to add something like "|| sym.$("woo").css({"margin-left">0px"}) to the move left code.

```
//Move RIGHT
if (e.which == 39) {
   sym.$("woo").css({"margin-left":"+=10px"});
}
//Move UP
else if (e.which == 38) {
    sym.$("woo").css({"margin-top":"-=10px"});
}
//Move Left
else if (e.which == 37) {
    sym.$("woo").css({"margin-left":"-=10px"});
}
//Move DOWN
else if (e.which == 40) {
    sym.$("woo").css({"margin-top":"+=10px"});
}
```

EDIT:

I changed the Left if statement to the following:

```
else if (e.which == 37 && ($("woo").css("margin-left")>0)) {
```

It seems to be working to some extent except for now it won't move left at all!  I tried doing <0 too in case I was screwing up a sign but it won't let me move the element left either.

ANSWER:

Well it turns out that the syntax of returning values is a little different than i thought.  To return the left margin instead of using the dash like how i used to set it, I had to do as below.

```
sym.$("woo").css('marginLeft')
```

And then to actual make it an int and compare it I used this.

```
if(parseInt(sym.$("woo").css('marginTop'))>0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the syntax of returning values is a little different than i thought.  To return the left margin instead of using the dash like how i used to set it, I had to do as below.

```
sym.$("woo").css('marginLeft')
```

And then to actual make it an int and compare it I used this.

```
if(parseInt(sym.$("woo").css('marginTop'))>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of a CSS property by calling the [`.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(...).css('margin-left')
```

Comment: I updated the question, your answer helped to a good extent though

Comment: You need to parseInt the value from `.css()` as it returns a string. 

`parseInt($("woo").css("margin-left"))`

Comment: What exactly does parseInt return? Because if margin-left returns a string, does that string include the px label?

Comment: Because when I use an if statement which has parseInt(...) > 0 it doesn't work still.